# Accelerometer getting data but not updating CGrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, accelerometer

```
-(void)startUpdates
{
    NSTimeInterval delta = 0.005;
    CMMotionManager *mMananager = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];
    if ([mMananager isDeviceMotionAvailable] == YES) {
        [mMananager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:delta];
        [mMananager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error) {
            self.xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", deviceMotion.userAcceleration.x];
            self.yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", deviceMotion.userAcceleration.y];
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(deviceMotion.userAcceleration.x + self.myBox.frame.origin.x, deviceMotion.userAcceleration.x + self.myBox.frame.origin.x, 10, 10);
            [self.myBox setFrame:frame];
        }];
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm calling once in the `viewDidLoad`. The Labels are updating but the box is not. It's rendering initially, but not changing with the accelerometer. How do I do this?

Comment: Is `self.myBox` non-nil? Is `frame` what you expect? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Not using auto layout, and self.myBox is not nil. I have it rendered.

Comment: Can you post the code of myBox? @MattBettinson